# Trouble with Strongly Typed DataSets

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, dataset

I am making a TimeClock in C# where the user creates a username and password and then the info gets saved to a database. Well, everytime I reference the DataSet I get the error: "an object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'TimeClockProject.loginsDataSet.Logins.Get'"

Here is the code:

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.ComponentModel;
   using System.Data;
   using System.Drawing;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using System.Windows.Forms;
   using System.Security.Cryptography;
   using System.Data.Sql;
   using System.Data.SqlClient;


   namespace TimeClockProject
   {
       public partial class Form1 : Form
       {
           public Form1()
           {
               InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void AddUser(string username, string password, string confirmPass, string email)
    {
        //Loop through Logins Table
        foreach (DataRow row in loginsDataSet.Logins)
        {
            //And look for matching usernames
            if (row.ItemArray[0].Equals(username))
            {
                //If one is found, show message:
                MessageBox.Show("Username already exists");
                return;
            }
        }

        //Confirm pass must equal password.
        if (password != confirmPass)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Passwords do not match");
        }
        //Password must be at least 8 characters long
        else if (password.Length < 8)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Password must be at least 8 characters long");
        }

        //If there is no username
        else if (username == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Must have Username");
        }
        //If all is well, create the new user!
        else
        {
            loginsDataSet.LoginsRow newUserRow = loginsDataSet.Logins.NewLoginsRow();

            string EncryptedPass = HashPass(password);
            newUserRow.Username = username;
            newUserRow.Password = EncryptedPass;

            loginsDataSet.Logins.Rows.Add(newUserRow);
            registerUserName.Text = String.Empty;
            registerPassword.Text = String.Empty;
            registerConfirmPassword.Text = String.Empty;
            MessageBox.Show("Thank you for Registering!");
        }
    }

    public string HashPass(string password)
    {
        SHA256 sha = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();

        //compute hash from the bytes of text
        sha.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password));

        //get hash result after compute it
        byte[] result = sha.Hash;

        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
        {
            //change it into 2 hexadecimal digits
            //for each byte
            strBuilder.Append(result[i].ToString("x2"));
        }

        return strBuilder.ToString();
    }

    private void registerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddUser(registerUserName.Text, registerPassword.Text, registerConfirmPassword.Text, registerEmail.Text);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: the error is telling you what the issue is.. where do you actually declare the DataSet.. can you show all relevant code..?

Comment: I didn't think I needed to declare a DataSet if I had already created the SQL DataBase in Visual Studio.

Comment: well sounds like you need to understand the difference between Instance and static, also how does Visual Studio know anything about Sql Databaser and it's objects.. you need to understand the two are not related..

Comment: @MethodMan Also, That is all of the code I currently have.

Comment: then you need to declare it at your class level give it a public or private access level for example private DataSet loginDataSet = null; then create a new instance of the dataset.. also where are you binding the dataset you would be better off declaring it as a DataTable other wise to access the datatable from the dataset you will need to get at it's datatable this way`datSet.Tables[0]` etc... use google it will be a life saver if you need to find working examples

Comment: relatively new or not you know there is something called `Google` there are tons of working examples online as well as here on `SO` where you can get examples. this is part of learning.. which is doing.. also do not use typed datasets.. you will get yourself caught in a bind later on.. create stored procedures to return data from your database using the C# sql database objects..

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issues, did away with the typed dataset